# Python regular expression(.map file parsing)

Tags: python, expression

I want to make a program that parses a .map file and I can't figure out what regular expression should I use to identify the name of a section.

`.text                  00040000    00000d7e`
I want to get `.text` string from this line. There is no other(whitespace character) before it. What regular expression should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `split`:

```
yourString.split(' ')[0]
```

It will print:

```
.text
```

Comment: I also figured out by myself that "^([.]\S+)" would work. Thanks anyway.